# Twisted data being read/written by client?

Tags: python, client, twisted

I'm learning twisted so I can integrate it with a blackjack pygame I have.  When figuring out how to pass the data from one client to server and then to other clients I was trying to see how I could manipulate the strings that normally get printed to the terminal in each clients screen in this example:

When I say manipulate, I mean to change the datatype to list, int, tuple, etc. of the 'data', print information of it `(type(data))`, and have conditionals for any keywords.

```
from twisted.internet import stdio, reactor, protocol
from twisted.protocols import basic
import re

## when client receives data from server // the client script checks then blits ##

class DataForwardingProtocol(protocol.Protocol):
    def __init__(self):
        self.output = None
        self.normalizeNewlines = False

    def dataReceived(self,data):
        if self.normalizeNewlines:

    ## see if data is == to secret ##
    ## this never returns True ? ##
            if data == 'secret':
                print "This line isn't secure"
            else:
                data = re.sub(r"(\r\n|\n)","\r\n",data)
        if self.output:
            if data == "secret":
                print "This line isn't secure"
            else:

         ## this will return the error message below ##
         ## so I'm very unsure of what is going on with 'data' ##
                self.output.write(type(data))

class StdioProxyProtocol(DataForwardingProtocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        inputForwarder = DataForwardingProtocol()
        inputForwarder.output = self.transport
        inputForwarder.normalizeNewlines = True
        stdioWrapper = stdio.StandardIO(inputForwarder)
        self.output = stdioWrapper

class StdioProxyFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    protocol = StdioProxyProtocol

reactor.connectTCP('192.168.1.2', 6000, StdioProxyFactory())
reactor.run()
```

Returns:

```
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 84, in callWithLogger
    return callWithContext({"system": lp}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 69, in callWithContext
    return context.call({ILogContext: newCtx}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 118, in callWithContext
    return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 81, in callWithContext
    return func(*args,**kw)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 614, in _doReadOrWrite
    why = selectable.doRead()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 203, in doRead
    return self._dataReceived(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 209, in _dataReceived
    rval = self.protocol.dataReceived(data)
  File "Downloads/trial.py", line 22, in dataReceived
    self.output.write(type(data))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/_posixstdio.py", line 53, in write
    self._writer.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/process.py", line 174, in write
    abstract.FileDescriptor.write(self, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/abstract.py", line 335, in write
    self._tempDataLen += len(data)
exceptions.TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()
```

So I can never 'check' the 'data' and when I try to print out anything about the data or change its type I get an extensive error?  Is there something obvious I'm missing or is this the wrong way to even go about it?  If it helps here is the [server](https://paste.lugons.org/show/3ydYkKJIcoDIIZjEDERk/) script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call type() it returns the type of the object, and not a string representing the type of the object.

You could check the type like this instead:

```
>>> aString = 'abc'
>>> anInt = 123
>>> type(aString) is str
True
>>> type(aString) is int
False
>>> type(anInt) is str
False
>>> type(anInt) is int
True
```

The data you receive will not be a list, tuple or some other kind of object unless you serialize it. Check out the module `Pickle` to see examples of how you can serialize objects!

Comment: Its not about doing this on the commandline but, I'm going to try and pass it back as a string like `str(type(data))`

Comment: J.F. Sebastian I'm not sure what you mean but, in my comment above it prints without error the `type` not in the way I was looking for though.

Comment: @Qiau I wasn't aware that I needed to serialize.

Comment: @tijko: Yes but in your code sample you are trying to call write() with type(data) as argument and that will not work unless you cast it to a string before.

Comment: @tijko: common thing :) check out the module "Pickle"

Comment: @Qiau see what you mean, I've changed it to a str.

Comment: @Qiau My end goal is having the blackjack pygame clients receive tuples/lists from each other through the server do you think this pickle module will be the way to go?  I could just pass strings too but, if you think this would be better?

Comment: @tijko: the advantage of using pickle is that you don't have to rewrite loads of code if you change your mind and want to send custom classes or other objects later on :)

Comment: @tijko: `pickle` is not a good option to pass objects over network (it is too powerful and insecure). `json` could be used to pass simple types such as lists, dicts, numbers, strings.

Comment: I read something that said the data should be sanitized is this correct?  I'm using this on my local network for a pygames/blackjack script so its not a security thing(thanks for the heads though).  On your other part with the power, you think this is using a sledgehammer to bang nails?